# I cannot deploy anything into my production org because of the Goal object deprecation

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment-error, work.com, spring22

Latest Spring 22 release on Saturday has deprecated some of the Work.com objects:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356306&type=1

One of these objects is the standard object `Goal` which we are using in our org.

**The Problem**

From Saturday I cannot deploy anything into my org - I always get the error:

> GoalARIUD line 8, column 9: Invalid type: Schema.Goal

Where `GoalARIUD` is a trigger I have on the `Goal` object

I have tried many ways to delete this trigger (I have also other classes that use the Goal object but they do not produce an error for now) and do other stuff

**What have I tried:**

1. Deploy a field with sfdx
2. Deploy any other component with sfdx
3. delete the trigger with sfdx destructiveChanges and: `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`
4. delete the trigger with `sfdx force:source:delete -m`
5. deploy the trigger after changed to a different object

All produce the same error:

> GoalARIUD line 8, column 9: Invalid type: Schema.Goal

I want to remove this trigger to make deployment pass without errors

This is a very weird problem and because it prevents me to deploy anything, it is a critical problem

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does the user you are deploying with have "WDC user" checked on their user details?

Comment: Thanks @codeulike, yes I have the "WDC User" license on my user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to fix this with the rarely used `destructiveChangesPre.xml` (see the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm)).

Your `destructiveChangesPre.xml` file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>GoalARIUD</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

Your package.xml can be empty:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

These should be the only two files in your mdapi directory.

Use `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -l RunLocalTests -d mdapi -u usernameOrAlias -w 100` to run the deployment.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, but I run this and still get the same error

Comment: sorry again @sfdcfox - I have added the files into a separated folder mdapi  and pointed to there and not it worked!!!!!

Comment: @ItaiShmida Yay! Glad I was able to help you out here, hopefully it'll be good for others that come along with this problem.

Comment: I want to say - @sfdcfox you are such a big saver, as always
you are the king of Salesforce!